# Microfocus ALM REST API - Get Test sets in specific path

Tags: rest, alm, hp-alm

I am trying to get test-sets from ALM using the REST API, but, if I use the following I get 45,000 entries due to the number of years that the company has been using it:

> http://ipaddr:8080/qcbin/rest/domains/a/projects/b/test-sets?query={test-set-folder.hierarchical-path[*]}

I would like to only get test sets under 'Root\CoreProjects\Salency', but if I try that I get 0.  This is what my url is like:

> http://ipaddr:8080/qcbin/rest/domains/a/projects/b/test-sets?query={test-set-folder.hierarchical-path[Root\CoreProjects\Salency*]}

Is it possible to do this please?  Thank you

Comment: It is possible, but the way the rest API takes the parameter is different.You can not specify "Root\CoreProjects\Salency*", the hierarchical path is the internal representation of the folder hierarchy.

Ref: https://github.com/macroking/ALM-Integration/blob/master/ALM_Integration_Util.py

Comment: @Barney Thank you for the link, are you able to highlight the lines of code I am interested in please as there are 899 lines and very limited comments (as some seem incorrect).  Thank you xx L